# How do I create this MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called `customer` which has, among others, a column called `name` and a column called `first_name_start`. I want `first_name_start` to be equal to `SUBSTRING(name, 1, 4)`. How would I create a trigger that makes sure this happens?

Comment: Are you sure you need do denormalize your table?

Comment: On what conditions do you want this trigger to fire? On Inserts only, Updates to the Name Field? We need more information.

Comment: Both inserts and updates to the `name` column. Nick, I am sure. I wish I didn't have to denormalize but I can't get the performance I need otherwise. (I checked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET NEW.first_name_start = SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 1, 4);  
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  SET NEW.first_name_start = SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 1, 4);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately, I didn't get time to test this, it might be completely wrong.

Comment: This does work - I had just tested a nearly identical thing. This only handles inserts, but the OP doesn't specify inserts/updates/everything.

Comment: @Erik: the OP did ask for updates to also be handled in a comment on his question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a view which adds the `first_name_start` if you really need it as a column?  Then you won't be storing redundant data, but you will be able to use it as if you were.

Comment: That would be the most logical thing to do, and I wish I could, but it just doesn't perform well enough.

Comment: Interesting.  Did you test the solution where you have the substring column (populated without triggers of course) and find it to be fast?  If so, it's a bit unfortunate the MySQL can't make the "most logical" solution perform well.

Comment: I just did my query and put a `WHERE SUBSTRING(...` and it was ridiculously slow.

Comment: What if you use `LIKE "abcd%"` rather than using `SUBSTRING` in your query?

Comment: No, that's just not the kind of comparison I'm doing. I'm also doing some more complex stuff like `SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name, ' ', -1), 1, 3)` so `LIKE` is unfortunately not an option.